# TabbedPage change icon

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a `TabbedPage` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
    android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"
    BarBackgroundColor="#2196F3"
    BarTextColor="White"
    android:TabbedPage.BarItemColor="#66FFFFFF"
    android:TabbedPage.BarSelectedItemColor="White">
```

But instead of changing the `BarSelectedItemColor` to white, I want the icon to get a gradient like this:
[image]

But I don't think that it is possible, so instead of "Giving it a gradient", I want to just change the home icon from:
[image] to [image]
But I have no idea how to enter that property!?
Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Comment: Hi, it seems can not set a gradient color for `BarSelectedItemColor` directly. It might need to use a generated icon to achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you check this out for your solution
https://xamgirl.com/extending-tabbedpage-in-xamarin-forms/